# Converting an arraylist to a linked list in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

I need help trying to rewrite this program using a linked list. Any help you can give me would help. I have never used linked lists before, and so far looking online has just confused me. Here is my code that is using an arraylist.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String stdID, sName, fName, lName, mName;
    int testScore1, testScore2, testScore3,totalNoHours;
    float cGPA;
    Students workobj;
    //****************************************External Output*****************************************************
    PrintWriter output;
    output = new PrintWriter(new File("StudentRecords.txt"));
    //****************************************External Input******************************************************
    try {
        //opening the file for input
        FileInputStream istream = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(istream);
        //creating an arraylist to store student objects
        ArrayList<Students> AllStudents = new ArrayList<Students>();

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            //first I will read the student id
            stdID = input.next();
            //next I will read the student name
            fName = input.next();
            lName = input.next();
            if (input.hasNextInt()) {
                mName = "";
            } else {
                mName = input.next();
            }
            sName = fName + " " + lName + " " + mName;
            //next read in the test scores
            testScore1 = input.nextInt();
            testScore2 = input.nextInt();
            testScore3 = input.nextInt();

            //next read in totalNoHours
            totalNoHours = input.nextInt();
            //next read in cGPA
            cGPA = input.nextFloat();
            //creating a student object
            Students StudentRecord = new Students(stdID, sName, testScore1, testScore2, testScore3,totalNoHours,cGPA);
            //now store this in allstudents
            AllStudents.add(StudentRecord);
        }//end of while

}//end of main

}//end of program
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question here. It is not appropriate on StackOverflow to put all your code in a question and ask people to just have a go at it. Read the help center if you want to find out more about what is appropriate here.

Comment: Just replace everywhere you see `ArrayList` with `LinkedList`

Comment: Okay sorry this is one of my first times using this site. I will take a look at the help center for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LinkedList<Student> list = new LinkedList<Student>();
for(Student s: AllStudents)
    list.add(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
     List<Integer> t=new ArrayList<Integer>();
     t.add(1);
     t.add(2);
     t.add(5);
     t.add(3);
     System.out.println("ArrayList upcating to list");
     for(Integer x:t)
     {
         System.out.println(x);
     }
     System.out.println(t instanceof ArrayList);
     System.out.println(t instanceof LinkedList);
     t=new LinkedList<Integer>(t);
     System.out.println("After upcasted to linkedList");
     for(Integer x:t)
     {
        System.out.println(x);
     }
     System.out.println(t instanceof LinkedList);
     System.out.println(t instanceof ArrayList);
    }
```

Comment: please add some explanatory detail, so that the OP can *understand why* you have written the code this particular way